# Save object to localstorage for short time

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a client-server system, and the client gets noitification every time something is changed (if she is involved). I don't want the user to get a new message if she just got involved, so I want to save the info in localstorage for short time and when she get notification, just to check if the localstorage still contins the element so in the notification function I want to have somethink like:

```
localStorage['currentTender'] = currentTender;
setInterval(function(){localStorage['currentTender']=null},10000);
```

and at the beginning of every time to check

```
{
    if(localStorage['currentTender'])
    ...
    ....
}
```

But it doesn't look very elegant to me. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `sessionStorage` instead `localStorage` .

Comment: Can u please explain why?

Comment: sessionStorage will store your data in short time compare to localStorage will be permanent until your flush it.

Comment: In my case i need to prevent notification only for realy short time. let's say 10-15 sec. so in that case i will need to flush it anyway. no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like socket.io to push the notification, or if you want to stall the notifications, set a session variable.